# How does one use OpenFileDialog in C# in visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, openfiledialog

I have written a custom dialog (form) that I can use in a C# program that behaves much like a "File - Open" menu command and brings up a window where a user can select a file or directory.

The question I have is this.  It has "My Computer" as its root.  How can I have it so that it searches on a Network?  If the file or directory is located on a network.

Or better yet, in Visual Studio 2010, is there some sort of canned FileOpenDialog that I can use right away?

I tried calling the OpenFileDialog as described in the example code at
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx
but the compiler does not seem to like `DialogResult.OK` as used in this line of code:

```
if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
```

The compiler says:

> Error 1   'System.Nullable' does not contain a definition for 'OK' and no extension method 'OK' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried using the namespace Microsoft.Win32 instead of System.Windows.Forms and neither worked.  They both produced this error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to use a WinForms (`System.Windows.Forms`) dialog.
Here is the [MSDN page for WPF dialog boxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773.aspx) from the `Microsoft.Win32` namespace.

An excerpt:

```
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
dlg.FileName = "Document"; // Default file name
dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt"; // Default file extension
dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt"; // Filter files by extension

// Show open file dialog box
bool? result = dlg.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:  missed the WPF tag.  My bad.  What Henk Holterman said.

Have you added the namespace that the example tells you to:  `System.IO`?

I might be wrong, but it sounds like you have created a variable called `DialogResult` which is of type `System.Nullable`